# How do I know which Linux package to install for my Linux AMI

Tags: linux

```
 Ubuntu/Debian
 Red Hat/Fedora/CentOS
 Mac OS X
 openSUSE
 FreeBSD
 OpenBSD
 Gentoo
```

I have an application which has been natively packed on the above platforms, how do I know which one to install on my Linux AMI on EC2.

```
uname -a displays the following
Linux ip-10-315-48-29 3.7.31.31-83.9.amzn1.i686 #1 SMP Sat Feb 18 20:11:16
UTC 2011 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's obviously some kind of Linux, so look for a file in /etc that ends in -release or _version:

```
ls /etc/*-release /etc/*_version
```

That should help you determine which Linux distribution you have. lsb-release is usually Ubuntu, while fedora-release, redhat-release indicate Fedora, RedHat, or CentOS. You can find a more complete listing [here](http://linuxmafia.com/faq/Admin/release-files.html).

Alternatively, you can see if rpm or dpkg are installed by trying to run those commands:

```
rpm --version
dpkg --version
```

If dpkg is installed, it's probably Ubuntu/Debian based. If rpm is installed, it's probably RedHat/CentOS or openSUSE based.

Comment: dpkg command not found. RPM version is 4.8.0. /etc/system-release says its an Linux AMI and /etc/*-version doesn't exist. So it should be Redhat or CentOS based, correct?

Comment: Probably. It could be openSUSE based, but chances are if it's cloud-computing or VPS related, it'll be RedHat/CentOS-based. So what you want is the 32-bit i386,i486,i586, or i686 RedHat package. Hope that helps!